# How to make Application Indicator 2D?

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, workspace-switcher

Linear arrays of workspaces are difficult to navigate after you have more than just a few.
2D arrays of workspaces for Linux have been around for a decade or two, and make getting to another workspace OrderOf(2*(sqrt(n)-1)) instead of OrderOf(n-1). For my case, I use 16 workspaces in a 4x4 array.  Getting to another workspace takes at most 6 moves, and you get a feel for where each workspace is in the 2D array. For the linear case, it takes at most 15 moves, and it's difficult to get a feel for where you currently are or how to get to another workspace.

Please support 2D workspaces in the Application Indicator, and the "motion animation" that is displayed when changing workspaces.  In Gnome 44, moving vertically looks like you're moving vertically, horizontal movement looks horizontal. In 45, movement animation is always left or right, even when moving "up" or "down".

Comment: Bug reports and problems should be [Reported on Launchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) so that developers can see, track and fix these issues.

Answer (score 1):

The workings of Gnome Shall can be customized with Gnome Shell extensions. There is an extension that exists for a long time, and remains being well maintained, that implements workspaces in a grid: [Workspace Matrix](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1485/workspace-matrix/) by mzur.

Note that this is a user site, with users like you and me. It therefore makes no sense to request some changes here. Instead, you can file suggestions and issues to the [Gnome Shell developpers](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME).